# Symfony2 validate only on creation

Tags: symfony

I have some entity and want to validate one field of this entity only on create object.

Example: I have Post entity and title has to have at least 10 characters when I create Post, but when I update it it can have less characters.

How can I do it with Symfony2? It's possible with default validator and default forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `Length` constraint for the title attribute to a dedicated [validation group](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) that will only be validated when the entity is not updated.